# use of calling functions in a loop

Tags: function, loops

This is a really complex code, but bear with me.

This code is used to check for palindromes. the problem I am having is not knowing how to call functions from in another function and in a loop.

This is the line in question:

```
if (new_num != rev)
    {
      while (higher != calc_reverse(higher) && lower != calc_reverse(lower))
    {
      higher = calc_reverse(number++);
      lower = calc_reverse(number--);
    }
```

Below is the code for the second half of my program which is involved in the error.
when I use this I just get "rev (number)" to print in an infinite loop until I force end the code.

```
//Function Declaration
int calc_reverse(int new_num)
 {
 //Local Declarations
  int count = 0; // number of digits in the number
  int rev = 0; //the reverse of the number
  int last; //the last digit of the number

 //Calulations
  while (new_num > 0)
   {
  last = new_num % 10;
  rev = last + (rev * pow(10, count));
  new_num = new_num / 10;
  count++;
   }
  printf("rev %d \n", rev);
  fflush(stdout);
  return(rev);
 }

//function Decleration
void calc_closest(int count, int new_num, int rev, int  number)
{
 //Local declerations
   int higher = 12; //the higher palindrome
   int lower = 12; // the lower palindrome

   printf(" %d, %d \n", new_num, rev);
   fflush(stdout);
 //Calculations
   if (new_num == rev)
    {
      printf("The value input (%d) is a compact palindrome. \n", number);
    }

   if (new_num != rev)
    {
      while (higher != calc_reverse(higher) && lower != calc_reverse(lower))
    {
      higher = calc_reverse(number++);
      lower = calc_reverse(number--);
    }
   if (higher == new_num && lower == new_num)
    {
      printf("Closest palindromes to %d are: %d, %d \n", number, lower, higher);
    }
   else if(higher == new_num)
    {
      printf("Closest palindromes to %d are: %d \n", number, higher);
    }
   else if (lower == new_num)
    {
      printf("Closest palindromes to %d are: %d \n", number, lower);
    }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same variable, "number", to count both up (number++) and down (number--).

That won't work. When you add one and then subtract one, you're left with the same number you started with, leaving you in an infinite loop.

You will need to use two separate variables.

Alternately, you can use just one ascending counter from which you calculate both the higher number and the lower. E.g.: i=0,1,2,3..., higher: number+i, lower: number-i. "number" here would never change from the initial value.

Comment: Alright I think that worked, I just have to tweak somethings that occur early in the code (mainly the reverse function as it seems to not to always work). I will let you know once I get those parts fixed. Thanks for the help!!!